# Why is intercepting a FileInputStream to FileOutputStream transfer with FilterOutputStream orders of magnitude slower?

Tags: java, jvm, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

**Context**

I am attempting to get feedback during a data transfer. Different cases occur, but the particular case I am dealing with is a FileInputStream to FileOutputStream copy.

The actual stream copy loop is done with org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.

Note that I am an experienced developer, however I am a java neophyte. The optimizations of the JVM are not well known to me.

**Problem**

I am wrapping the FileOutputStream in a java.io.FilterOutputStream to intercept the transfer and count as follows :

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("path"));
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("path2"));
FilterOutputStream filterOutput = new FilterOutputStream(output);
IOUtils.copyLarge(input, filterOutput, new byte[32 * 1024]);
```

Now, when I do this, with the actual "do something" removed (in the above example, removed my implementation with the basic FilterOutputStream, so as to not impact the tests), copying a 450Mb file plummets from 5-10secs (without FilterOutputStream  wrapping) to approx 8 minutes.

**A couple facts**

- Measured on a windows x64 8 core machine
- Copying from local LAN to my machine's SSD
- One core is 100% busy until the operation ends
- Network and disk are barely busy (1-2%)
- I've tested using Buffered input/output streams around my file streams with varying buffer sizes, and not using them.
- I've varied the actual data buffer size.
- None of the above two variations proved to have any meaningful impact in the order of magnitude difference between with and without
  the FilterOutputStream wrapping.

**Question**

Why does this occur? And is there any way to work around it?

I am guessing that the JVM is able to detect standard patterns of file copying and delegate it directly to the OS. It seems a bit strange to me that it would do that wrapped in the Buffered streams, but couldn't do it with the write method being indirected by the FilterOutputStream.

Right now the only work around I see is to implement a listener right into the copy loop instead of piping OutputStreams, but since that requires reimplementing the loop instead of using the Apache utils, and adding and passing that listener down a few layers of APIs, I am looking for information before I go down that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-) will copy byte by byte for the following method:

> public void write(byte[] b,
>            int off,
>            int len)
>              throws IOException
>
> Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this output stream.
>   The write method of FilterOutputStream calls the write method of one argument on each byte to output.
>
> Note that this method does not call the write method of its underlying input stream with the same arguments. Subclasses of FilterOutputStream should provide a more efficient implementation of this method.

Comment: I was going to answer "yes, I've read the comment", but then I read it again... thanks for pointing out the obvious. The 1-byte write is obviously not very jvm-optimization friendly. The actual in-house FilterOutputStream implementation I was debugging overrides that write(byte[] b, int off, int len) method to intercept, but then forwards it to super instead of out. D'oh!

Answer (score 0):

A `BufferedInputStream` is a `FilterInputStream`, ditto for the output side. Can you use those in place of Filtered streams and look at the performance again? That might compensate for any IO related slowness.